# DynamoDB query returns zero results

Tags: c#, nosql, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to query a DynamoDB table to find a product based on it's url.

The table has three fields: Title, Description & Url.

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsDBLogins.AccessKey, awsDBLogins.SecretKey);
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast2);

var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, "Products");
```

With the above code i'm able to connect to the table. I then execute the below query which does not return any error's however the list of results is empty. I am expecting one result to be returned where the Url matches "test".

```
var productUrl = "test"
QueryOperationConfig config = new QueryOperationConfig()
{
    Filter = new QueryFilter(productUrl, QueryOperator.Equal, "Url"),

    AttributesToGet = new List<string>
    { "Title", "Description", "Url" },

    ConsistentRead = true,
};

var ProductItem = table.Query(config);
```

While this does not work in the code, I'm able to find the entry in the database when looking list of item's from the AWS web portal / console so I know that the entry exists.

Am I making a mistake in my filter?

Comment: Is productUrl the hash key of the table? If not, what is the hash key of the table?

Comment: @notionquest productUrl is indeed the hash key of the table.

Comment: It should be Filter = new QueryFilter("Url", QueryOperator.Equal, productUrl); The key and value should be reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hash key name and value should be reversed. First parameter is the key name and third parameter is the value.

```
Filter = new QueryFilter("Url", QueryOperator.Equal, productUrl)
```